# how to recover the deleted user's data on ubuntu server?

Tags: server, data-recovery

this is Yugandhar Reddy A, i deleted a user named sudheer in ubuntu server with the following command

sudo userdel -r sudheer

the above command deleted the home directory of sudheer .

but i need his home directory,so what i have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

All file deletions on linux are final.

You can always hand your disk to data recovery companies if their price is worth your data. Or browse the internet yourself for hard disk recovery programs. Sometimes you can be very lucky and recover most of your data.

You can create a temporary "Recycle Bin" folder (e.g /tmp/trash) and make it a habbit to refrain from deleting anything, rather mv to trash. Also be extremely cautious using the -r switch (remove or recurse), specially on a multiuser system.